# Scala Option to get the key value

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Is there any better way to write this code:

```
if (a == "value") map.get(key)
else None
```

Where `map` is a Scala map, and `map.get(key)`returns an `Option[A]` value.

I have tried this so far:

```
PartialFunction.condOpt(a == "value") {case true => map.get(key)}.flatten
```

Comment: What's wrong with the way it's currently written?

Answer (score 1):

TBH I like the way you've written it above:

```
if (a == "value") map.get(key)
else None
```

It's concise and conveys the intenion. If you really don't like it, one more way I can think of is:

```
Option(a).filter(_ == "value").flatMap(_ => map.get(key))
```

Answer (score 1):

Available in Scala 2.13.x:

```
Option.when(a == "value" && map.keySet(key))(map(key))
```

Or ...

```
Option.when(a == "value")(map.get(key)).flatten
```

Comment: Why do you need `map.keySet(key)`?

Comment: It's shorter than `map.isDefinedAt(key)` but, admittedly, a bit more obscure in its intent.

Comment: Why do you need to search the key space for the key, of `map.get(key)` will tell you if it's there or not (by returning an Option)?

Comment: It's true. We could skip that test and `.get()` from the `Map`, but then we'd have to `.flatten` the result. It's a trade-off.